# Date Format issue in Scala

Tags: javascript, java, scala, playframework, simpledateformat

I have written my current web application in PlayFramework v2.2.4

On the web page application is trying to display dynamic Date format, from the following list.

- yyyy-mm-dd
- dd-mm-yyyy
- mm-dd-yyyy
- dd-mmm-yy

After user's selection piece of source written in Scala

```
<input id="schedule_date" class="wide input" type="text" data-date-format="@views.Util.getOrgTimeFormat()" placeholder="Date" name="@form("date").name" value="@form("date").value" />
```

Above piece of source working well for 1st three items but for 4th item expected output is different.

- Output for 4th item: 23-066-2017
- Expected output for 4th item: 23-JUN-2017

Could you please identify mistake in above source or any class/method which needs to be used for it.

Answer (score 0):

You've hit a common gotcha. All the `mm` and `mmm` should be uppercase for month. Lowercase `m` represents minuites, not months.

Comment: Udha Thanks for your comment but alreay tried mmm with uppercase well. Also if it has been the case then it won't be working for first three items.

Comment: You should post your date formatter code as that's most likely where things are going wrong. Also, shouldn't `dd-mmm-yy` be `dd-mmm-yyyy`?

Answer (score 0):

same use case in mine also. i used java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
and then u can convert using format java.util.date.